# How to use AND condition in an ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have these three tables:

```
create_table "cocktail_ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "cocktail_id"
t.integer "ingredient_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["cocktail_id"], name: "index_cocktail_ingredients_on_cocktail_id"
t.index ["ingredient_id"], name: "index_cocktail_ingredients_on_ingredient_id"


create_table "cocktails", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "title"
t.string "ingredients"
t.text "method"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
```

I'm trying to do a seach that returns all the cocktails that contain ALL of the ingredients in my search.
So far i've managed to come up with this:

CocktailIngredient.where(ingredient_id: [1, 4]).map(&:cocktail).uniq

Which returns all the cocktails that include the ingredient_id of 1 or 4. I am trying to return only the cocktails that contain BOTH ingredients with the id 1 AND 4.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: while I research your issue... what is the goal of field `ingridients` in cocktails table?

Comment: To easily display ingredients from the cocktail to the user later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generalised version, if you have an `ingredient_ids` array:

```
cocktail_ingredients = [1, 4]
cocktail_ingredients = CocktailIngredient.where(ingredient_id: ingredient_ids).select(:cocktail_id)
cocktail_ingredients = cocktail_ingredients.group(:cocktail_id).having('COUNT(ingredient_id) >= ?', ingredient_ids.count)
cocktails = Cocktail.where(id: cocktail_ingredients.select(:cocktail_id))
```

Here is a tested scope for your `Cocktail` model (with Rspec and FactoryGirl). You'll just have to call `Cocktail.with_ingredients([1,4])`.

In cocktail.rb:

```
scope :with_ingredients, (lambda do |ingredient_ids|
   cocktail_ingredients = CocktailIngredient.where(ingredient_id: ingredient_ids).select(:cocktail_id)
   cocktail_ingredients = cocktail_ingredients.group(:cocktail_id).having('COUNT(ingredient_id) >= ?', ingredient_ids.count)
   where(id: cocktail_ingredients.select(:cocktail_id))
end)
```

And cocktail_spec.rb: https://gist.github.com/ArnoHolo/54b9259fbaa067d7abbf04a73d94ec40

Comment: I think such where chaining will always result into blank array, because this conditions contradict each other.

Comment: Yes, it returns a blank array when using the .where chain

Comment: Great! I've added a generalised version, if you have an `ingredient_ids` array.

Comment: @HoloHokkaido @pfrasdog Such solution is VERY unoptimized and is guaranteed bottle neck in the future. Also `Cocktail.where(cocktail_ingredients: { ingredient_id: ingredient_id })` will provide an error, isn't it?

Comment: @pfrasdog Check my response. It definetly should work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6544e5/2

Comment: Yes the `Cocktail.where(cocktail_ingredients: { ingredient_id: ingredient_id })` method provides an error.

`SELECT * FROM cocktails WHERE id IN ( SELECT cocktail_id FROM cocktail_ingredients WHERE ingredient_id = 1 UNION SELECT cocktail_id FROM cocktail_ingredients WHERE ingredient_id = 4 )`

This seems to return every cocktail that contains ingredient_id 1 or 4, not 1 and 4.

Comment: I forgot the `.joins(:cocktail_ingredients)` before the `where`, but I have edited it. @AntonTkachov : Your solution is working but is not generalised. (Not sure @pfrasdog is asking for it though)

Comment: @HoloHokkaido Yes, you is right. But I think, that you pfrasdog will need to make a subquery for each of ingredients. If you need assistance in generic solution, I can help with it. Union still provide not intersection, but all cocktails

Comment: Both methods working now. Thanks heaps for the help!

Comment: All right, I've come up with an optimized solution. I've edited my post one last time. :) @pfrasdog, don't forget to mark your question as solved!

Answer (score 1):

The best I found for now is:

`Cocktail.joins(:cocktail_ingredients).where(cocktail_ingredients: { ingredient_id: 1, cocktail_id: CocktailIngredient.where(ingredient_id: 4).select(:cocktail_id) })`

I don't think it's the best we can do, but it's MUCH MORE optimized then previous solution